# Ошибка: mac address are invalid in both cmos and flash

Tags: сеть, mac-address

Отдали системник в ремонт. Сказали оператива сломалась. Получили, запустил, проверил, работает. Была ошибка

> mac address are invalid in both cmos and flash

нажал F1 to Resume и все. Но логично оказалось, что интернет не работает. Я так понял, что слетел мак-адрес сетевой карты. И надо его зашить. Сложно это самому сделать или лучше отдать обратно? Косяк-то их.

Comment: Вы в биосе посмотрите на предмет mac адреса возможно что  написано что то не то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAC адрес можно изменить в Диспетчере устройств (если Windows), в свойствах сетевой карты. При этом желательно включить в BIOS режим PNP OS - "ON" (если там это есть). А сетевуха, как я понял, бортовая?

Answer (score 1):

Была такая проблема с новой материнкой. Помогло обновление BIOS